# How to count the labels in Blogger (per month)

Tags: search, count, label, blogger, blogspot

I would like to make a graphic illustration of: how many time have I used a specific label on my blog.

example:

- January (1)
- February (9)
- March (5)
- April (4)
- ...

Where the numbers in the brackets mean the COUNT(my label) GROUP BY month
So for example I used the "..." label 9 times during February.

I would like to make a bar chart or a line chart with the results.

Thanks

Comment: Never seen this before...perhaps may not be possible with blogger.
If the number of posts and labels is less....i guess a manual work by way of excel can be a good solution.

Comment: label used 173 times over 4 years in 1479 posts

Comment: is it possible to count the labels and fetch the values one by one using java script only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't find anything as good as I wanted to, but I had an idea: in the administration part, you can use filters for date and label, so it would not be too hard doing it by hand after all ...

Comment: Can you give us an example?